# How to creates a value in a cell nested in a cell

Tags: matlab, cell

This seems like a very easy question but I can't seem to work it out. Basically I have a number of cells: Face1, Face2, Scene1, Scene2. Each cell contains a value, for instance, Face1=15, Face2=23, Scene1=46, Scene2=9

Now I would like to group all these cells into one single cell called D, something like this D={Face1,Face2,Scene1,Scene2}. However, when I do this I get D={15,23,46,9}. This is not what I want. I'd like to keep the identity of each cell so when I call D{1,1} I'll get Face1, and when I call Face1, I'll get 15.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using structures? Try this:

```
D.face1 = 15
D.face2 = 23
```

You could also do it like this:

```
D.face(1) = 15
```

Let me know if that doesn't do it for you.

Comment: Good! I'm glad I could help. Structures are very powerful, especially when building GUIs. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) is a good link for some of the more subtle properties of structs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best "solution", but you could do something with [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).

First, create your variables.

```
Face1 = 15, Face2 = 23, Scene1 = 46, Scene2 = 9
```

Then, create the cell array containing the variable names, as strings:

```
D = {'Face1', 'Face2', 'Scene1', 'Scene2'}
```

You can query their values like this:

```
>> eval(D{1,1})

Face1 =

    15
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

Looks like you are using arrays, not cells. That is, I think your code looks like this:

```
Face1 = 15
Face2 = 23
Scene1 = 46
Scene2 = 9
D = {Face1 Face2 Scene1 Scene2}
```

Which would act as you describe.  Now `D{1}` returns `15`.

If you were using "cells", your code would look like this:

```
Face1 = {15}
Face2 = {23}
Scene1 = {46}
Scene2 = {9}
D = {Face1 Face2 Scene1 Scene2}
```

This is probably not what you want, but it is the cell solution. Now `D{1}` returns `{15}` and `D{1}{1}` returns `15`.

If you want to preserve the names in the composite data `D`, the a struct is probably the easiest thing. See Fletch's just-posted answer.